# Python: Create a grid and count the number of points in each grid cell

Tags: python, geospatial

I have a geodataframe with two columns: geometry and category.

The geometry column contains x and y coordinates for each point, and the category column contains a categorical value for each point.

I'm trying to create a grid, and then count the number of points that fall within each grid cell using Python. The end goal is to create a basic histogram (e.g., plt.hist()) of the counts in grid cells.

So far I have the following code, however, when I run the code it appears to just hang.. or it is just really really inefficient.

The grid cells I want to use are 1000 m by 1000 m (hence the +500 and -500 from each cell center).

Does anyone know how to grid and then count the number of points in each grid cell?

```
points_df.head()
Out[1]: 
  category    geometry
0   cat       POINT (476755.37 173256.16)
1   cat       POINT (459671.16 268477.14)
2   cat       POINT (516320.74 200363.71)
3   cat       POINT (505964.05 202886.12)
4   cat       POINT (442114.96 290854.97)


    #calculate grid cell centers
    x_cen = np.linspace(500, 659500, 660)
    y_cen = np.linspace(500, 1059500, 1060)

    cell_centers = []
    for x in x_cen:
        for y in y_cen:
            cell_centers.append({'center': (x, y)})

    #create dataframe of cell centers
    grid_df = pd.DataFrame(cell_centers)

    #create an empty column to hold the counts per cell 
    grid_df['counts'] = [0 for n in range(len(grid_df))]

    #count the number of points that fall within each grid cell
    for index1, row1 in grid_df.iterrows():
        for index2, row2 in points_df.iterrows():
            if row2.geometry.centroid.x > row1.center[0] - 500 and row2.geometry.centroid.x < row1.center[0] + 500 and row2.geometry.centroid.y > row1.center[1] - 500 and row2.geometry.centroid.y < row1.center[1] + 500:
                if row2.category == 'cat':
                    row1.counts += 1
```

I'll appreciate any help or ideas!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @tdelloro! Have you tried to use `numpy's` `histogram2d`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html It'll allow you to specify the gridding and return the counts for you in a way that's also easy to plot.

Comment: Thanks HAL, that solution worked! I was able to bin the points and count the number of points per bin using  np.histogram2d().